# How to get a value from json with delphi

Tags: delphi

I have this json and i want to get the **fname** value.
How can i do it with Delphi

```
{  
   "root":[  
      {  
         "customers":[  
            {  
               "fname":"George Makris",
               "Age":12
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

here is What i am doing Now but i dont think is the corect way

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var s,json:string;
      myObj:TJSONObject;
      myarr:TJSONArray;
begin

json:='{"root":[{"customers":[ { "fname":"George Makris","Age":12}]}]}';
myObj := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(json) as TJSONObject;
myarr := myObj.GetValue('root') as TJSONArray;
myObj := myarr.Items[0] as TJSONObject;
myarr := myObj.GetValue('customers') as TJSONArray;
myObj := myarr.Items[0] as TJSONObject;
s := myObj.GetValue('fname').value;
showmessage(s);
end;
```

Comment: what was th -1 for?????

Comment: I didn't downvote but it's probably because you didn't include a clear description of the problem you are encountering (ie, compiler error, error at runtime, incorrect values returned, etc). From the SO help, "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers"

Comment: i see i must read the rules.okey then thanks for the clear answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your example is close, but will leak memory, specifically the result of ParseJSONValue.

I prefer to use TryGetValue to validate if the content exists.  It also infers the type by the parameter used.  Here's a leak free example of both.

```
procedure TForm3.btnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  s, JSON: string;
  jo: TJSONObject;
  myarr: TJSONArray;
begin
  JSON := '{"root":[{"customers":[ { "fname":"George Makris","Age":12}]}]}';
  jo := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSON) as TJSONObject;
  try
    if jo.TryGetValue('root', myarr) and (myarr.Count > 0) then
      if myarr.Items[0].TryGetValue('customers', myarr) and (myarr.Count > 0) then
        if myarr.Items[0].TryGetValue('fname', s) then
          showmessage(s);
  finally
    jo.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: thats why i asked and i took -1 :)